# Adding part of an array to a drop down menu via its index?

Tags: java, arrays

I have created a drop down menu box with the following array `String[] fishWaterType = {"Freshwater", "Tropical",};`. When the user click's one of the two array options above I want one of two options to appear in another drop down option `String[][] myArrayChoice = {{"Goldfish"}, {"GuppyFish", "Angel Fish"}};` depending on what was clicked. I had planned to complete this action with an if/ else statement and access the two different options via their array index list. The only problem... `myArrayChoice.get(0)` doesn't work! Can anyone suggest a suitable method to access the index? Thanks!

Comment: you must try to have only a 2d array, make selection with 1st dimension and depending the choice take the 2nd dimension to show more options, also show some of your code! ;)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly? If it causes an error, which? If you include all the relevant code it will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `.get()` method works for retrieving items from lists. For arrays, you have to use the `[]` notation.

So:

```
List<String> list = ...
String s = list.get(n); // get nth item from list.

String[] array = ...
String t = array[n]; // get nth item from array

String[][] array2d = ...
String u = array[i][j]; // get value in i-th row and j-th column in 2d array
```